# Specifying base URL with mod_pagespeed?

Tags: apache, cpanel, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I've installed mod_pagespeed and I'm trying to figure out if this is possible to do.

Example URL:

```
<script src="/assets/build/js/test.js"></script>
```

The above URL is rewritten to this:

```
<script src="/assets/build/js/test.js.pagespeed.jm.QCz72nUS30.js"></script>
```

What I would like to do is for the URLs to be rewritten to the base of the website or to a folder that I specific.  For example, I would prefer the rewritten URL to appear like this:

```
<script src="/test.js.pagespeed.jm.QCz72nUS30.js"></script>
```

Or something like this:

```
<script src="/sample-folder/test.js.pagespeed.jm.QCz72nUS30.js"></script>
```

Is this something that's possible to configure with mod_pagespeed?  I want to do this for all images, javascript, and CSS files.  Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible with mod_pagespeed. Here are the only URL rewrite control options available to you:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/restricting_urls

You can rewrite the URL's with Apache's mod_rewrite. However, note the following limitations when doing so:

https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=676

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, because at least as described it wouldn't work.  Let's say on your site you have two different files called `test.js`:

```
/assets/build/js/test.js
/testing/test.js
```

And imagine you could tell PageSpeed to put everything at your webserver root:

```
/test.js.pagespeed.jm.QCz72nUS30.js
/test.js.pagespeed.jm.8U69T_7wiB.js
```

This would work as long as these resources stayed in PageSpeed's cache: it could use the hash portion of the url to look into its cache and find what resource the user wants.  But what happens when the cache gets full and something gets evicted?  Then a request comes in for one of these, it's not in the cache, and PageSpeed doesn't have enough information available to reconstruct the original url so it can regenerate it.  PageSpeed would have to 404 the request, which would break the page.